# Como atualizar minha versão do laravel 4.2.14 para última versão?

Tags: laravel, framework

Acabei um projeto laravel 8.
comecei outro projeto com laravel 9.
quando fui ver minha versão do laravel, descobri que estou usando version 4.2.14.

Iniciante no framework, não tenho ideia como atualizar, e no youtube e em outros foruns não achei respostas que me ajudassem.

Comment: Não compensa, da muito trampo.

Answer (score -2):

recentemente atualizei do 5 para o 9

Para fazer isso precisa atualizar uma versão por vez exemplo
laravel 4 para o 5,depois 5 para o 6

https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/upgrade#upgrade-5.0
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/upgrade#upgrade-6.0
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/upgrade#upgrade-7.0
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/upgrade#upgrade-8.0
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/upgrade#upgrade-9.0

e ai verificar os pactoes de terceiro para cada versão atualziada (rezar para não morrido os projetos no caminho)